# Apple Signin through Python

Tags: python, ios, jwt

I do have a problem with apple signin in python but it's mostly not python, just mysterious stuff....
So, I read this article
https://medium.com/@aamishbaloch/sign-in-with-apple-in-your-django-python-backend-b501daa835a9
It should be quite easy to implement it but my implementation doesn't work, so what I did is:
I've added appleapiprovider class which being used in rest framework, this AppleProvider being called this way:

```
provider = AppleApiProvider()
provider.verify_token(token_sent_from_ios_device) # NOT JWT TOKEN, just code.
```

and here is what happening in the method verify_token

```
def verify_token(self, token):
    client_id, client_secret = self.get_key_and_secret()
    headers = {'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    data = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'code': access_token,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri': 'https://example-app.com/redirect'
    }
    res = requests.post('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', data=data, headers=headers)

    def get_key_and_secret(self):
        headers = {
            'kid': KID
        }

        payload = {
            'iss': ISS,
            'iat': timezone.now(),
            'exp': timezone.now() + timedelta(days=180),
            'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
            'sub': 'com.APP.staging.signin',
        }

        client_secret = jwt.encode(
            payload,
            open('/etc/apple.pem', 'rb').read(),
            algorithm='ES256',
            headers=headers
        ).decode("utf-8")

        return 'com.APP.staging.signin', client_secret
```

And in result I get

```
{error: 'invalid_grant'}
```

Any idea ? It's not a problem with client_id and client_secret, I tried to use there just absolutely random strings and it says, invalid_client
Possible duplicate is: [New Apple Sign in keeps throwing Error HTTP 400 Invalid_grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753274/new-apple-sign-in-keeps-throwing-error-http-400-invalid-grant)
but there's no exact solution to my problem, it should be quite small and I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: I suggest you didn't enable sign in with apple for you key. Or App ID for signin misconfigured.

Comment: Other suggestion is [as docs says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens) _The code is single-use only and valid for five minutes_ I tried fresh code and everything rocks

Comment: hi demon, did you try exactly this code ?

Comment: No. But mine is very similar.

Comment: @demon.mhm what exactly do you mean by "tried a fresh code"? is it a code extracted from the JWT token? Or something else?

Comment: `ValueError: Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.`

Answer (score 1):

My error was using the JWT token as the 'code' parameter instead of the authorization_code.

I am using the '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication' React Native package to handle Apple Sign in on client side. I think the data transmitted there may be similar across Native and other packages.

What this package returns on apple sign-in is the following object:

```
{
  authorizationCode: string <- this should be sent as "code"
  authorizedScopes: [],
  email: string <- will be null, except for first request. To reset for testing, disconnect the app from apple signin
  fullName: {...} <- will contain null values only, except for first request. see above
  identityToken: string
  nonce: string
  realUserStatus: 1
  state: ?
  user: string  <- should be used to identify users
}
```

The identityToken is a JWT token that when decoded contains the following data:

```
header:
{
  "kid": string, <- can be used to identify the apple public key one can use to verify the signature (fetched from here https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys)
  "alg": "RS256"
}

payload:
{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": <your package ID>,
  "exp": number,
  "iat": number,
  "sub": string, <- same as "user" in above datastructure
  "nonce": string,
  "c_hash": string,
  "email": "asd@privaterelay.appleid.com", <- contains the email, even if the above structure does not contain it
  "email_verified": "true",
  "is_private_email": "true",
  "auth_time": number,
  "nonce_supported": true
}
```

One confusing aspect is, that the email can be null in the first obj, but still be contained in the JWT. It is a bit unclear whether we need the JWT token in all cases. It seems like for a simple authentication service the authorizationCode and user parameters suffices.