# Apple Sign In Python

Tags: python, django, oauth, jwt, sign

I want to make an apple sign in with social auth python. Now I have a piece of code below. When I do a request, I get an invalid grant error. I think that 'id_token' is not valid. But I don't know how to get that id_token, because I get the id_token after the request. Can anybody help me. Big Thanks!

```
headers = {
   'alg': 'ES256',
   'kid': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_KEY
}

payload = {
   'iss': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_TEAM,
   'iat': now,
   'exp': now + TOKEN_TTL_SEC,
   'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
   'sub': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_CLIENT,
}

client_secret = jwt.encode(
   payload, 
   settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET, 
   algorithm='ES256', 
   headers=headers
 ).decode("utf-8")


headers = {'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
data = {
    'client_id': 'com.scread.app',
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'code': 'id_token',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
}

res = requests.post('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: does this one help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579470/apple-signin-through-python? Not an apple expert, but it seems to be quite similar.

Comment: Thanks jps. But I saw that post too. But didn't help me out. I must do something with parameter code. I have now id_token, but I must request it some way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the service id must end like .app. Thus for example com.company.app. That was the solution for me.